# The excerpt: Display text OR image OR video

Tags: excerpt

Is it possible to adjust the excerpt so it will show text **or** one image **or** one video?

The following codes makes it possible to show all of the above, but i'd really like to limit that, dependent of whats included in the post..

```
<?php 
function improved_trim_excerpt($text) {
        global $post;
        if ( '' == $text ) {
                $text = get_the_content('');
                $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
                $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $text);
                $text = strip_tags($text, '<iframe>, <p>, <img>');
                $excerpt_length = 66;
                $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
                if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
                        array_pop($words);
                        array_push($words, '[...]');
                        $text = implode(' ', $words);
                }
        }
        return $text;
}
?>
<?php
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_trim_excerpt');
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to consider using post formats. You can see [my answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51705/9844) about altering the "Read More" text, but it would apply similarly to you. For the video portion, you might want to create a custom field to hold the video URL, but otherwise, I imagine this would be quite simple to setup.

Rather than filtering the excerpt, this would also give you the option to replace `the_excerpt()` with:

```
get_template_part( 'excerpt', get_post_format() );
```

Then you could use `excerpt.php` for the default/fallback snippet, `excerpt-video.php` for videos, and `excerpt-image.php` for images. Alternately, you'd use something like this in your filter to test the post format:

```
if( get_post_format() == 'video' ) { // etc...
```